# How can I restore an org file from a backup?

Tags: org-mode, backup

I recently made the mistake of accidently deleting a portion of my home folder. I lost some org-documents for notes and things that I'd like to recover. Luckily, my `.emacs.d` directory and the backups directory inside was not. How do I restore the Org files from these backups?

--update--

I solved this by renaming the backup file as the original org file and everything reformatted properly.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any pre-written elisp code that would automate this for backup files and your use case... (but for autosave files there is `recover-file`, and there is a related question [recover backup files](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/29142/recover-backup-files) with some answers that might be helpful).

Luckily, since Org files are plain text and Emacs backups are not incremental, you can just copy the files to where you want them to be, rename them (making sure the extension is .org), and you're good to go. To restore many files one could write some code to automate this.